# How to convert PostgreSQL insert

Tags: postgresql

Error on LastUpdated where `now()::abstime::INT4`, command is not accepted on newer Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE glines (
        Id SERIAL,
        Host VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        AddedBy VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        AddedOn INT4 NOT NULL,
        ExpiresAt INT4 NOT NULL,
        LastUpdated INT4 NOT NULL DEFAULT now()::abstime::int4,
        Reason VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Comment: which postgreSQL version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract()` to get the Unix time. And you should probably avoid using internal data types to prevent such problems in the future ([The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-datetime.html) clearly states: "The types `abstime` and `reltime` are lower precision types which are used internally. You are discouraged from using these types in applications; these internal types might disappear in a future release.").

```
... DEFAULT extract('epoch' FROM now()) ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I'll have to edit whole SQL old backups for all my SQL restore to new would work.

Comment: I also want to know replacement of now()::ABSTIME::int4 when INSERTING, it seems that it doesn't accept extract('epoch' FROM now()) if I want to insert.

Comment: When Tried to insert something using this command. INSERT into users (user_name,password,language_id,last_updated,created_ts) 
VALUES ('Admin','07d976a29bdb3ff42e19c102852151b28097bbad',1,now()::abstime::INT4,now()::abstime::INT4);

I got this error

ERROR:  type "abstime" does not exist
LINE 2: VALUES (2,1,500,now()::abstime::INT4);